# Why cannot C++ unpack template arguments into the default constructor?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

Here it is

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, typename... Args>
T* getSingleton(Args... args) {
    static T instance(args...);
    return &instance;
}

class MyType1 {
public:
    MyType1(int val) {}
    MyType1(const MyType1&) = delete;
    MyType1(MyType1&&) = delete;
};
class MyType2 {
public:
    MyType2() {}
    MyType2(const MyType2&) = delete;
    MyType2(MyType2&&) = delete;
};

int main() {
    std::cout << getSingleton<MyType1>(11) << std::endl; // works
    // std::cout << getSingleton<MyType2>() << std::endl; // doesn't work

    return 0;
}
```

Got error:

> prog.cpp: In instantiation of ‘T* getSingleton(Args ...) [with T =
>   MyType2; Args = {}]’: prog.cpp:24:37:   required from here
>   prog.cpp:5:27: error: use of deleted function
>   ‘MyType2::MyType2(MyType2&&)’   static T instance(args...);
>                              ^ prog.cpp:19:2: note: declared here   MyType2(MyType2&&) = delete;   ^~~~~~~

Comment: Works fine for me on VS2015 and [gcc 7.3](https://godbolt.org/g/fFhnyC).

Comment: And [Clang 7.0.0](https://wandbox.org/permlink/1Raa6Jt37inf96f9).

Comment: seems to be bug of old gcc

Comment: It also works as early as gcc 7.1.